# How to compare current date with the previous one in Datatable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

Im trying to compares two dates to know if the "weight" of an animal went up or down, this is my Weight table:

[image]

"id_ganado" is the animal id, and I get all the weights of an animal in my "Animal Model" like this:

```
public function pesos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Peso', 'id_ganado');
}
```

This is how I call all the weights in a Datatable:

```
public function index(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        return datatables()
            ->eloquent(Peso::where('id_ganado', $id)->orderBy('fecha', 'desc'))  
            
            ->editColumn('fecha', function ($peso) {
                return [
                    'fecha' => Carbon::parse($peso->fecha)->format('d/m/Y'),                       
                ]; 
            })

            //Here Im trying to calculate what I want
            ->addColumn('ganancia', function ($peso){
                
                
            })            
            ->addColumn('btn2', 'ganado.engorde.peso.tableCol.tabAction')
            ->rawColumns(['btn2'])
            
            ->toJson();
    }

    return view ('ganado.engorde.peso.index', ['ganado' => Ganado::findOrFail($id)]);
}
```

So how can I compare the current date with the previous one in every value in the table?

Comment: I don't think there is any clean solutions to do exactly what you want with Yajra. Only the current row is injected into the closure.

Comment: @KurtFriars So there is not a way to inject all the weights of that animal in that column and compare them.